# How to calculate survey bias due to preference for first answer?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I was recently given the results to a survey in which participants chose answers to questions they would be likely to randomly answer, and in which the survey population is known to have a preference for the first answer. Survey takers participated because of a free prize, and now I need to figure out how to account for the bias introduced by the preference for the first answer. How would I go about doing this mathematically?

Here is an equivalent example:

### Favorite Representatives Survey

Pick your favorite Utah representative:

1. Jason Chaffetz (2080 selected)
2. Rob Bishop     (1380 selected)
3. Chris Stewart  (580 selected)
4. Mia Love       (746 selected)

Pick your favorite Kansas representative:

1. Lynn Jenkins   (1890 selected)
2. Tim Huelskamp  (2910 selected)
3. Mike Pompeo    (540 selected)

Pick your favorite New York representative:

1. Lee Zeldin     (2584 selected)
2. Peter King     (1123 selected)
3. Steve Israel   (1790 selected)
4. Kathleen Rice  (1521 selected)
5. Gregory Meeks  (1207 selected)

Pick your favorite Alaska representative:

1. Donald Young   (4585 selected)

Pick your favorite Hawaii representative:

1. Mark Takai     (1900 selected)
2. Tulsi Gabbard  (2700 selected)

As you can see from the data there is a pretty clear trend toward first-choices, but at the same time there are some cases where higher-numbered choices won. What general methods can I use to quantify the effect of the first-choice advantage, and try to find what the results would have been if not for that bias?

Comment: Why not randomize the order?

Comment: The only reasonable way to solve this problem is to give the questions in a random order. If this is not possible, then one should leave the result untouched. Distorting the results (even in a clever way) would be much worse than not accounting for a possible first choice preference. All of this is imho.

Comment: @lulu Unfortunately, the survey is done, and can't be redone, so the best that we can do is remove the bias from the results

Comment: I would learn a probabilistic Model (Bayesian network or Markov Random Field), then sort the sampling depending on whether the learned model explains them better than a pick-the-answer-randomly hypothesis then re-learn with only the first set of samples, etc....

Comment: I'd say there is no responsible way to remove a bias like this without resampling.  If I had to, I'd form test groups with random orders and compare the results....but that sounds more or less equivalent to re-polling.

Comment: (+1) to @lulu this design is flawed$\implies$ GIGO